# XSLT 2.0 grouping fails with non-existent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

after several days I'm still desperately trying to convert an XML-Output to CSV.

Source XML contains several levels of additional "meta" entries which are only present if not empty!

Example:

```
<export>
 <key authority="0" description="tp 2013-06-13" id="2" name="tp" number="17">
  <meta>
   <additional>
    <field label="Datum" value="21.12.2013"/>
   </additional>
  </meta>
 </key>
</export>
```

"label" is the grouping element and hence the column header.

Following different suggestions here I was successful with this snippet of XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="kf" match="field" use="@label"/>

<xsl:variable name="keyAddDataCols" as="element(field)+">
<xsl:for-each-group select="/export//key/meta/additional/field" group-by="@label">
<field key="{current-grouping-key()}"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$keyAddDataCols/@key" separator="{';'} "/>
```

But if there is not a single occurrence of key/meta/additional/field in the Source-XML the conversion fails with

> XTTE0570: An empty sequence is not allowed as the value of variable
>   $keyAddDataCols

I tried to leave out the "casting" (… as="element…"), but then it doesn't work at all.
I tried to check the existence of a field with "xsl:if test=field" but saxon9 complains none theless that keyAddDataCols is not defined.

For now I'm out of ideas and very grateful for every single hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy for the eventual output to be empty if there are no `key/meta/additional/field` elements then simply change

```
<xsl:variable name="keyAddDataCols" as="element(field)+">
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="keyAddDataCols" as="element(field)*">
```

(`*` instead of `+`) to allow the variable to contain an empty sequence.

Comment: OMG! Just 1 character to change! So easy! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tino the sequence type specifiers are just like regular expressions - `?` = zero-or-one, `*` = zero-or-more, `+` = one-or-more

Comment: Yeah, I reckoned that, but was unable to find a documentation (which seems to be kind of a rule with XSLT…) ;-)

Comment: @Tino with XSLT 2.0 it's compounded by the fact that the spec is split between several inter-related documents (XSLT itself, XPath 2.0, the data model and the functions and operators spec). For reference the definition of sequence types comes from [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#doc-xpath-SequenceType).